# MODx & .htaccess issue

Tags: .htaccess, modx, modx-revolution

I have been trying to get FURLs working in MODx. Following resource covers this topic in details - http://rtfm.modx.com/display/revolution20/Using+Friendly+URLs. However once the changes to .htaccess are made, the site is no longer available. Here is my .htaccess file:

```
# Friendly URLs Part
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
# Force all pages to go to www.domain.com for SEO
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.dev\.domain\.co\.uk [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.dev.domain.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
# Friendly URLs
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
# Additional Settings Follow
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/gif A2592000
ExpiresByType image/jpeg A2592000
ExpiresByType image/png A2592000
BrowserMatch "MSIE" brokenvary=1
BrowserMatch "Mozilla/4.[0-9]{2}" brokenvary=1
BrowserMatch "Opera" !brokenvary
SetEnvIf brokenvary 1 force-no-vary
```

Any ideas what may be the issue?

Comment: What do you mean 'no longer available'? Are you getting a server error or a MODx error?

Answer (score 0):

Change `.htaccess` back to original - https://github.com/modxcms/revolution/blob/develop/ht.access

Comment: +1. If you're going to downvote, care to explain why? Start again with the original .htaccess, adjust only the non-www to www rules. Ignore the Additional Settings until you have furls working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Default htaccess file for modx

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]



# Rewrite secure requests properly to prevent SSL cert warnings, e.g. prevent 
# https://www.example.com when your cert only allows https://secure.example.com
#RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443
#RewriteRule (.*) https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]



# The Friendly URLs part
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Check [this](https://allhtaccess.info/modx-default-htaccess-file/) for full htaccess file